How to make a dynamic color pack in Vuetify based on the theme?
How can I configure Vuetify to use a dynamic color pack that switches between light and dark themes based on the current theme? Is there a specific way to set this up in the Vuetify scss configuration?
Here’s an example of the colors that I have in variables.scss:
Light Theme Colors:
$emotion: (
  "joy": #d1bf0e,
  "trust": #9bb700,
);

$colors: (
  "emotion": $emotion,
);

When the theme switches to dark, I want to use different colors:
Dark Theme Colors:
$emotion-dark: (
  "joy": #38a5fb,
  "trust": #c23a3a,
);

$colors: (
  "emotion": $emotion-dark,
);


Are you asking how to add named colors (like primary), or how to add a full theme (like dark)? Have you looked at the color pack documentation?

@MoritzRingler No sir, what you are referring to is the color pack configuration within vuetify.js. However, what I'm asking about here is how to make a color pack in variables.scss for Vuetify that can change based on the current theme.

That's similar to how Vuetify handles colors like 'red lighten-1' or 'blue darken-2'. For example, in the light theme, the color 'emotion joy' would use #d1bf0e. If the theme switches to dark, it would use #9bb700 instead

Should have said "semantic colors" when referring to primary. Color packs are defined in scss, but those are just named colors (like blue-darken-2), they are not affected by theme - blue is blue. You can generate shades like joy-lighten-2 this way, but it has nothing to do with theme.

Semantic colors (like primary) are theme-specific, the intended way to define them is by extending each theme in JS, as described in the link above. If you want to do it in scss, you have to write the classes yourself, like .v-theme--light .bg-joy (check the theme implementation to see what you need).

@MoritzRingler writes SCSS with $colors: ("emotion": $emotion,); like this, and it works. I can use it on my elements with classes like "emotion--text text--joy" for text color.
My issue is that I want the "emotion joy" color to change based on the current theme without set on vuetify plugin, just pure on vuetify.scss.

Previously, I came across some posts and articles mentioning that SCSS is generated during the build process, so it’s not possible to change SCSS values based on the theme dynamically. Is it right, sir?

Yes, when you extend color pack (base is defined here), you get text and background classes for all of them (see sccs code here). This happens during build. It has nothing to do with theme and is not affected by it. You can use these colors in the color prop (i.e. <VBtn color="joy"/>) but it is unaffected by theme.

Theme CSS is generated during runtime (see link above for code) and updated, when theme changes. This is JS, you cannot patch into this with SCSS. However, you can generate classes from SCSS that are affected by theme classes. But yes, you cannot rebuild the SCSS color pack definitions when theme changes, as SCSS is compiled during build, not during runtime.

Basically, I think you have two options: either extend the theme colors (in JS) or add theme-specific CSS color declarations (possibly build through SCSS). Extending theme colors in JS is much easier, since you don't need to know which CSS classes are actually needed, you just register name and color for each theme. Is this not suitable for you?
